# Data structure to Filter Data Quickly

Tags: data-structures, filtering

I am doing a bit of research into making an efficient filtering algorithm when it comes to many properties of specific data. This is kind of a fun project for me to learn new data structures.

for example, say I wanted All RPG's on Playstation Which had English releases.

Now I want to allow for much more complex queries.

Is there a good data structure to handle filtering attributes like this, without the need to give all of the attributes. Instead I can give only a few and still find the correct games?

I currently plan to have "buckets" which will describe an attribute, for example all Genre's game ID's will be in one bucket, and so forth. Then I will use a hash algorithm to add 1 to that game, and only use games which have the correct value after the search.

But I want to try to find a faster or easier method, any suggestions when it comes to filtering many attributes to find sets of items?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "without the need to give all of the attributes"? Are you saying you have N attributes and you want to find the items that match l < N of the attributes, or are you saying that you don't want to compute an index for each attribute?

- Hashing each attribute into buckets will give you O(1) time at the expense of O(n) space to store each index.
- You could sort your list by one or two attributes to make some lookups O(logn) at the expense of having to do the sorting up front for O(nlogn) time
- You could get kinda clever with [bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) for your attributes and let some attributes overlap. This would lead to some false-positives, but you could filter those out after the fact. This gives you constant-space with constant-time lookup in the average case (but O(n) time in the worse-case).

Comment: It's funny because I have been thinking about using the second one, well at least similar to it, I was thinking I would keep track of how many items are in each bucket, so I can find the smallest bucket as my "base" to filter off that. That way I am starting with the smallest possible amount for this particular filter.

I agree I have a problem with storage, because I have to think about combination of attributes too, like a game that has both "Action" and "RPG" Genre would need an index "Action-RPG" which either action AND rpg would look at as well as their own.

Comment: I wonder if there is a good way to predict collisions, for example the number 10 15, 19 and 30 always hit the same locations, so for a single game, I would need like a 10 point overlap for each game, meaning there are ONLY 10 numbers per attribute that can overlap...I will look at this, I will make this as the answer if no one else provides anything better.

Thanks.

Comment: The multiple-index thing is what a database will do. If you're filtering for `X=1 and Y=2` it'll generate a query plan using statistics (size of the buckets) and look for all the items that have `X=1` and then overlap that with items that have `Y=2`. Databases also have composite indexes that will do the `Action-RPG` trick you point out.

Comment: The only problem I have with using a database is the more attributes I have the more joins I require. Unless of course I flatten the tables, but then I have to worry about limiting the number of each attribute a game can have, for example, they can only have 3 genre's etc... I tried looking into a good way of doing it in cassandra, but I couldn't find anything worth while.